# OS Walk Exception handling

Tags: python, xml, parsing, exception, os.walk

I am not very experienced when it comes to exception handling. There is one type of error I know my code will get when it reaches directories that have "Archive" in the file path and looks through certain files. In the file search there are some files that are saved as binary and when it goes through to parse it it will give a "ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line1, column 0". What type of exception is this, and how do I go about making this definition? I also do not know where the right place is to look in the python documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
current_dur = r'Defined Contributions'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dur):
for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.ldm') or file.endswith('.cdm') or file.endswith('.pdm'):
            full_file_name = os.path.join(root, file)
           
            print(os.path.join(root,file))
            #for i in file_results:
                #WE are parseing it.
            tree = ET.parse(full_file_name)
                #We then get the root.
                #Maybe 
            gotten_root = tree.getroot()

            
            for elm in gotten_root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
                print(elm.text)

            for Model in gotten_root.findall('.//{object}IntraModelReport'):
                rootId = elm.attrib
                file_Name = Model.find("{attribute}Code").text
                unique_ID = Model.find("{attribute}ObjectID").text
                employee_badge = Model.find("{attribute}Creator").text
                print( file_Name, unique_ID, employee_badge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch the exception and move on.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#exceptions

```
try:
    tree = ET.parse(full_file_name)
except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
    print(f'Invalid xml: {full_file_name}')
    continue
```

Comment: I just tried it but it is still stopping the running of it. I put the code in the line below after print(file_Name, unique_ID, employee_badge).

Comment: you should wrap the call to `parse` with try/except (assuming you get ParseError) (I have added `continue` to the code so it should skip the broken file)